# What's the most efficient way to get data from a model in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm new to CakePHP, and still figuring out the basics. Right now I'm a bit mystified by the process to get one or more fields from a model (from inside another linked model).

So far, I have this:

```
$this->user->id = 123;
$this->User->read();
$field1 = $this->User->data['User']['field1'];
$field2 = $this->User->data['User']['field2'];
```

Which seems awfully verbose.

And this:

```
$this->user->id = 123;
$field1 = $this->User->field('field1');
$field1 = $this->User->field('field2');
```

Which seems less long, but results in two queries.

What I *used* to do in these situations, pre-Cake:

```
$this->User = new User(123);
$field1 = $this->User->field1;
$field2 = $this->User->field2;
```

or when I felt like typing:

```
this->User = new User(123);
$field1 = $this->User->getFieldOne();
$field2 = $this->User->getFieldTwo();
```

So, the question: am I missing some magic in CakePHP by which to accomplish this task, or do I have to live with typing a lot?

Comment: The magic you're missing is Ruby. I don't mean to be a troll, it's just that Cake is an attempt to get the magic of Ruby into PHP without realizing that PHP just isn't up to it.

Comment: Why would you assign a value in an array to a single variable?  That's pretty inefficient.  You don't need to use $field1; just do a Model::find() and use the returned value effectively.

Answer (score 4):

You will never believe, but there is a short way :-)

```
$this->User->find('all', array('fields'=>array('field1', 'field2')));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arrayOfFiels = array('field1', 'field2');
$this->User->id = 123;
$userFields = $this->User->read($arrayOfFields);
```

Or something like:

```
$userFields = $this->User->read(null, 123);
```

In both cases, $userFields will be an array with `User #123` data. In the second one, due to the first argument set as `null`, all fields will be fetched. Second argument (optional) sets an id, which can also be pre-set earlier like in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use 'read' or 'find' or 'query' to get data from model

read

```
$fields = array('field1','field2');
$this->data = $this->User->read( $fields,$someid );
```

find

```
$this->data = $this->User->find('all',array('fields'=>array('field1','field2') );
```

query

```
$this->data = $this->User->query("select field1,field2 from user where id=$someid;");
```